How do I take my aerator off a faucet?
I've lived in this old house for almost 4 years and the water pressure in the bathroom sink is obnoxiously low. I've been trying to remove the aerator/whatever this thing is and nothing seems to work. No clue what brand of sink it is or if I can even fix it by myself.

The edit button has a mountain/sun icon for pictures. Maybe soak the end in a bit of vinegar for a few minutes at a time.

@crip659, users with 1 rep don't have image privileges. AHM, post an image on a hosting service and link us to it. Where there's a will there's a way, and we can't help with what you've told us.

Is there a shut-off valve in the pipes on the way to the faucet that isn't properly open? Is it the hot or the cold which has a low flow rate?

make sure it is aerator in there, identified by small slit, then use plier to unscrew it
